# Next.js + Production build + Webp format images

Tags: build, path, next.js, production, webp

I have a few images that are already in `.webp` format.

`/public/images/Image.webp`

and they work on my dev local environment but when I build and view the static site the image fails to show.

```js
<picture>
    <source
        srcset="/images/architect/Header-Image.webp"
        type="image/webp"
    />
    <img srcset="/images/architect/Header-Image.webp" />
</picture>
```

Image of file location:

[image]

```
/public/
    images/
        architect/
```

Comment: Are you seeing any request errors in the dev tools' `Network` tab?

Comment: How are you viewing your "static site"? Don't forget to serve the site (using [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or `next start`). **_DO NOT_** just open the generated HTML files in your browser. Also, change your fallback `img`'s extension to `JPG`. If you are not able to fix the bug, then please add a link to codesandbox/stackblitz/repository so that we can reproduce it and help you. The given information is not sufficient for us tell anything with confidence.

Comment: I do ```next build && next export``` and then put the out folder content onto IIS (Microsofts hosting service)

Comment: It works when I run the dev server (yarn dev) but not on production + deployed.

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs If you are able to see image in localhost but in production it wont worked means add unoptimized prop in Image tag like this`<Image unoptimized/>`  or else in `next.config.ts` add:

```js
images: {
  unoptimized: true
}
```